# How do you include conditional and non-conditional calls in an RxJS mergeMap?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

After an api call fetches data I need to call a number of further actions on `FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS`.

The `'RESET_IMAGE_DATA'` and `'INITIALISE_FILTERS'` actions must be called on every `'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS'`. However, `'SET_PIVOT'` must be called only when `action.context === 'pivot'`.

So, there are 2 possible cases.

In the first case, `'RESET_IMAGE_DATA'` and `'INITIALISE_FILTERS'` are called.

In the second case, `'RESET_IMAGE_DATA'`, `'INITIALISE_FILTERS'` and `'SET_PIVOT'` are called.

I've tried all kinds of solutions with no success and my latest attempt is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const loadDataEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS'),
    mergeMap(action => {
      if (action.context === 'pivot') {
        return of({
          type: 'SET_PIVOT',
        });
      }
      return of(
        {
          type: 'RESET_IMAGE_DATA',
        },
        {
          type: 'INITIALISE_FILTERS',
        }
      )}
    )
  );
```

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with it. Maybe you could make it shorter with a single ternary operator.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `of` to `from` so you send an array, since an array allows easy dynamic insertion.

Like this:

```
const loadDataEpic = (action$, state$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType('FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS'),
        mergeMap(action => {
            const pivotActions = action.context === 'pivot'
                ? [{ type: 'SET_PIVOT' }]
                : [];
            return from([
                ...pivotActions,
                {
                    type: 'RESET_IMAGE_DATA'
                },
                {
                    type: 'INITIALISE_FILTERS'
                }
            ]);
        })
    );
```

Comment: Cheers, exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const loadDataEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS'),
    mergeMap(action => {
     const isPivot = action.context === 'pivot';
     return of(
       { type: 'RESET_IMAGE_DATA' },
       { type: 'INITIALISE_FILTERS' },
       ...(isPivot ? [{ type: 'SET_PIVOT' }] : [])
     );
    })
  );
```

it will only add the action `SET_PIVOT` if the condition is true.

p.s.: If you don't like the syntax you could use an array and push it based on the condition and then return it with `of(...actions)`